# Why is the transformer for time series forecasting faster than RNN?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, transformer, prediction, attention, sequence-modeling

I've been reading different papers which implements the [Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) for time series forecasting. Most of the them are claiming that the training time is significantly faster then using a normal RNN. From my understanding when training such a model, you can encode the input in parallel, but the decoding is still sequential unless you're using teacher-forcing.

What makes the transformer faster than RNN in such a setting? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: For those of you interested in the concept of teacher-forcing, have a look at the paper JT-VAE. Essentially, teacher-forcing is the trick of replacing the predictions with the actual ground-truth values, so that future predictions are based on correct past histories.

Comment: @nbro Thank you for your comment. I am aware how teacher-forcing works but if you're training a model in such a way the model is not gonna learn how to recover from a mistake. On the other hand if scheduled sampling is used i think the model might perform better, but this will significantly increase the training time.